# Decorator to clear thread context for Spring @Scheduled annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Want to clear the thread contex post execution of the functions annotated with `@Scheduled` in spring boot

Usage

```java
@Scheduled(fixedDelayString = "10000")
    publi void doSomething() {
}
```

Config for scheduled thread pool

```java
@Bean(destroyMethod = "shutdownNow")
        public ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService() {
            return Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(5);
 }
```

Have created a simple decorator to solve the same

```java
package com.demo.decorator;

import com.demo.utils.GeneralUtils;
import org.springframework.core.task.TaskDecorator;

public class ThreadContextDecorator implements TaskDecorator {

    @Override
    public Runnable decorate(Runnable runnable) {
        return () -> {
            try {
                runnable.run();
            } finally {
                GeneralUtils.clearContext();
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Not sure how to add it in bean of `ScheduledExecutorService`

Answer (score 0):

According to this open issue on spring repository: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/23755 there's no direct way to do this.

My solution is to first create a configuration for task scheduler:

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
public class SchedulingConfiguration implements SchedulingConfigurer {
  @Override
  public void configureTasks(ScheduledTaskRegistrar taskRegistrar) {
    var threadPoolTaskScheduler = new CustomThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
    threadPoolTaskScheduler.initialize();

    taskRegistrar.setTaskScheduler(threadPoolTaskScheduler);
  }
}
```

Then create a custom ThreadPoolTaskScheduler:

```
public class CustomThreadPoolTaskScheduler extends ThreadPoolTaskScheduler {
  @Override
  protected ScheduledExecutorService createExecutor(
      int poolSize,
      ThreadFactory threadFactory,
      RejectedExecutionHandler rejectedExecutionHandler) {
    return new CustomScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(poolSize, threadFactory, rejectedExecutionHandler);
  }
}
```

while CustomThreadPoolTaskScheduler looks like:

```
public class CustomScheduledThreadPoolExecutor extends ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor {
  public CustomScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(
      int corePoolSize,
      ThreadFactory threadFactory,
      RejectedExecutionHandler handler) {
    super(corePoolSize, threadFactory, handler);
   }

  @Override
  protected <V> RunnableScheduledFuture<V> decorateTask(
  Callable<V> callable, RunnableScheduledFuture<V> task) {
    return new CustomTask<>(task);
  }

  @Override
  protected <V> RunnableScheduledFuture<V> decorateTask(
      Runnable runnable, RunnableScheduledFuture<V> task) {
    return new CustomTask<>(task);
  }

  private record CustomTask<V>(RunnableScheduledFuture<V> task)
  implements RunnableScheduledFuture<V> {

    @Override
    public void run() {
      try {
        // DO SOMETHING BEFORE....

        task.run();
      } finally {
        // DO SOMETHING AFTER....
      }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean cancel(boolean mayInterruptIfRunning) {
      return task.cancel(mayInterruptIfRunning);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCancelled() {
      return task.isCancelled();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isDone() {
      return task.isDone();
    }

    @Override
    public V get() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
      return task.get();
    }

    @Override
    public V get(long timeout, @IsNotNullable TimeUnit unit)
    throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException, TimeoutException {
      return task.get(timeout, unit);
    }

    @Override
    public long getDelay(@IsNotNullable TimeUnit unit) {
      return task.getDelay(unit);
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(@IsNotNullable Delayed o) {
      return task.compareTo(o);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isPeriodic() {
      return task.isPeriodic();
    }
  }
}
```